# IDF recaculation for existing documents in index?

Tags: elasticsearch, tf-idf

I have gone through  [Theory behind relevance scoring][1]  and have got two related questions

Q1 :- As IDF formula is `idf(t) = 1 + log ( numDocs / (docFreq + 1))` where `numDocs` is total number of documents in index. Does it mean each time new document is added in index, we need to re-calculate the IDF for each word for all existing documents in index ?

Q2 :-   Link mentioned below statement. My question is there any reason why TF/IDF score is calculated against each field instead of complete document ?

> When we refer to documents in the preceding formulae, we are actually
>   talking about a field within a document. Each field has its own
>   inverted index and thus, for TF/IDF purposes, the value of the field
>   is the value of the document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You only calculate the score at query time and not at insert time. Lucene has the right statistics to make this a fast calculation and the values are always fresh.
2. The frequency only really makes sense against a single field since you are interested in the values for that specific field. Assume we have multiple fields and we search a single one, then we're only interested in the frequency of that one. Searching multiple ones you still want control over the individual fields (such as boosting "title" over "body") or want to define how to combine them. If you have a use-case where this doesn't make sense (not sure I have a good example right now — it's IMO far less common) then you could combine multiple fields into one with `copy_to` and search on that.

Comment: Thanks.  Regarding point 1, You mean Es just creates the inverted index at the storage/insert time  wheres as score like TF/IDF is calculated at query time only ?

Comment: Yes. Every single change to the index would influence the score so there is no way to pre-calculate that for every possible query.

Comment: Any idea does google also calculates at query time ? Finding the score at query time  is a humongous  task considering the billion of documents. Is n't it ?

Comment: But do you have billion(s) of documents for your use case? I would assume that you are trying to solve a different kind of problem than Google.

Comment: Yeah I am just asking from google. I don't have that usecase